# Moodle login page site name show at top in error

Tags: moodle

I have installed a template in the moodle, in the middle login page at the top it shows some site name echo, from where I can remove this, thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Site administration" -> "Front page settings" and change the site name from there. Hope is helps.